# How should I map over two arrays without ruining the order of rendered items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

I'm trying to create a chat-bot with some additional features like sending and receiving voice audio. I used two different array states for rendering the text messages and audio messages. In the render section, I map over these arrays separately.

```
setMessageList((prevlist) => [...prevlist, {id: uuidv4(), message: currentMessage, type: "sender",}, {id: uuidv4(), message: "response.data.data.answer", type:"reciever"}]);


     setAudioList(prevState => [
      ...prevState,
      {id: uuidv4(), audio: audioUrlQuestion, type: "sender", isLoading: isLoadedVoice} , 
      {id: uuidv4(), audio: result.data.filePath , type: "reciever", isLoading: isLoadedVoice}
    ])
```

```
 {audioList.map(item => {
            if (item.type === "sender") {
                   //render sender audio tag
            }
            if (item.type === "reciever" && isLoadedVoice === false) {
              // ...
            } else if (item.type === "reciever" && isLoadedVoice === true) {
              //
            }
          })}
          {messageList.map((item) => {
            if (item.type === "sender") {
              //show sender messages
            }
            if (item.type === "reciever" && isLoadedMessage === false) {
               // show received mesgs
            
            } else if (item.type === "reciever" && isLoadedMessage === true) {
              //
            }
          })}
```

However, everything works in a right order only when user just send audio/text messages without any switching. For example, if your first message is audio and the second one is text, when you want to send the third message which is an audio type again it should show the audio after the text message. But it doesn't. Instead it will appear after the first audio message(before the text one).
So, how can I render voice messages and text messages in a right order after another?

Comment: [...audioList,...messageList].sort().map(................) ,  Please use sort method by create/message time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either sorting (constraints: ~nlogn complexity for each render, need timestamps), or putting them together into the same state array i.e.

```js
const [allMessages, setAllMessages] = useState([]);

...

setAllMessages([...allMessages, {type: "audio", item: {id: uuidv4(), audio: audioUrlQuestion, type: "sender", isLoading: isLoadedVoice}}, {type: "audio", item: 
      {id: uuidv4(), audio: result.data.filePath , type: "reciever", isLoading: isLoadedVoice}}]);

...

setAllMessages([...allMessages, {type: "text", item: {id: uuidv4(), message: currentMessage, type: "sender",}}, {type: "text", item: {id: uuidv4(), message: "response.data.data.answer", type:"reciever"}}]);

...

 {allMessages.map(({type, item}) => {
           if (type === "audio") {
if (item.type === "sender") {
                   //render sender audio tag
            }
            if (item.type === "reciever" && isLoadedVoice === false) {
              // ...
            } else if (item.type === "reciever" && isLoadedVoice === true) {
              //
            }
           } else if (type === "text") { 
if (item.type === "sender") {
              //show sender messages
            }
            if (item.type === "reciever" && isLoadedMessage === false) {
               // show received mesgs
            
            } else if (item.type === "reciever" && isLoadedMessage === true) {
              //
            }
           }
            
          })}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is simple Way ,

```
const audio = [{
    message: "Audio 1",
    time: 1
  },
  {
    message: "Audio 1",
    time: 3
  },
];
const message = [{
  mesage: "Text 1",
  time: 2
}];
[...audio,...message].sort(( a, b )=> {
  if ( a.time < b.time ){
    return -1;
  }
  if ( a.time > b.time ){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}).map((item)=> console.log(item))
```